# Tank always overruns me as Jake

Tags: resident-evil-6

I'm constantly getting overrun by the tank in Chapter 3 after I fall through the floor and the tank smashes the door. It doesn't give me time to react at all, I tried going forward according to the camera angle ("S" key) and forward according to the player's perspective ("W" key), while sprinting (holding "space") and without trying to sprint.

I found that this was a common problem and tried playing in offline mode [as this page suggests](http://segmentnext.com/2013/03/25/resident-evil-6-errors/), however I see no difference and keep dying all the time.

Am I doing something I'm not supposed to?, it looks like when Jake starts running I'm 1mm away from the tank, which to me is just stupid game design.

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue as well. What worked for me was moving sideways as well for some reason. So during the cinematic as he falls, hold space+S+D, and that may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [recent update](http://store.steampowered.com/news/10272/), it should solve that issue.

Comment: Well, it didn't fix this one

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to rehost the game.
I was running into this issue when playing co-op hosted by another person.
When I hosted (continuing from the checkpoint), it worked fine.

Comment: I'm playing on single player off-line

Answer (score 0):

I made it! Finally I understand how to do it. You need to hold S, D, F keys before and while the since till it let you to move but the point is, it must be the first time you're coming in game. It doesn't help after that. Hope you can pass this part.